# Knockout JS - make observable dynamically modified object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is possible to make dynamically changed JS object as a Knockout JS observable?

I mean I have `this.statuses = ko.observable({})` and when I call API and get response, I'll put the message here under some "identifiers". Later I need to get any "last" status if necessary:

```
  set_status(owner, status, api_response) {
    if (!(owner in this.statuses)) this.statuses[owner] = {};
    this.statuses[owner][status] = api_response;
  }

  get_status(owner, status) {
    if (owner in this.statuses && status in this.statuses[owner]) {
      return this.statuses[owner][status];
    }

    return '';
  }
```

and in the html template something like:

```
<div data-bind="text: get_status('owner_1', 'api_call_1')"></div>
```

I hope this is understandable, but if it is not clear, here is (not) working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/svezij/rLx4d1ua/61/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KnockoutJS observables are functions, thus to get their value they should be evaluated. In your case you just need to replace `this.statuses` to `this.statuses()` everywhere in the code where the value of observable is needed, like this:

```
set_status(owner, status, api_response) {
    if (!(owner in this.statuses())) this.statuses()[owner] = {};
    this.statuses()[owner][status] = api_response;
}

get_status(owner, status) {
    if (owner in this.statuses() && status in this.statuses()[owner]) {
        return this.statuses()[owner][status];
}
```

Also, the KnockoutJS observables does not track the object mutations, thus when mutating the value like below, it won't be detected:

```
this.statuses()[owner][status] = api_response;
```

In such cases, after the mutation of value like above, the observable should be "notified" that it's value has mutated, by calling the `valueHasMutated` method:

```
this.statuses.valueHasMutated();
```

Comment: I am sorry, I am a little stupid, of course observables are functions and in the real code I am calling it with `()`, I don't know why I did not use it in the example code, sorry for that. But the magic was `this.statuses.valueHasMutated()`, now, it looks like it works as I expect. Thank you very much. Here is working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/svezij/rLx4d1ua/66/.